# Some necessary information on taking two lists for plotting from a database within the Flask application

Tags: python, pandas

I'm just starting to learn the Python programming language and a tool for displaying various information - tables, graphs.
I am trying to add data to the initial SQ lite database. Using the Pandas library and pull out, take data from the table - take the date column in a variable and then the second column in the form of simple values. To plot a graph from two lists of data. Unfortunately, so far, everything is working out very hard. An error appears. Help is very much needed! If you tell me where you can pick up some necessary information on taking two lists for plotting from a database within the Flask application.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect, session
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

from dash_application import create_dash_application
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///blog.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


create_dash_application(app)


class Article(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    intro = db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=False)
    text = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Article %>' % self.id


class Tablekot(db.Model):
    index = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    time = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True)
    tnarvozd = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True)
    tteplonposlekotla = db.Column(db.Integer)
    tuhgaz = db.Column(db.Integer)


db.create_all()


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template("about.html")


@app.route('/posts')
def posts():
    articles = Article.query.order_by(Article.date.desc()).all()
    return render_template("posts.html", articles=articles)


@app.route('/posts/<int:id>')
def post_detail(id):
    article = Article.query.get(id)
    return render_template("post_detail.html", article=article)


@app.route('/newdiagram')
def newdiagram():
    cxn = sqlite3.connect('blog.db')
    data = pd.read_excel('new46_1k1.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1')
    data.to_sql(name='tablekot', con=cxn, if_exists='append', index=False)
    cxn.commit()
    cxn.close()
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///blog.db')
    tit = pd.read_sql_table('tablekot', con=engine, columns='time')
    tiu = pd.read_sql_table('tablekot', con=engine, columns='tuhgaz')
    labels = tit
    values = tiu
    return render_template("newdiagram.html", labels=labels, values=values)
```

---

```
return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
File "C:\Flask_gd\venv\app.py", line 72, in newdiagram
    data = pd.read_excel('new46_1k1.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1')
    data.to_sql(name='tablekot', con=cxn, if_exists='append', index=False)
    cxn.commit()
    cxn.close()
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///blog.db')
    tit = pd.read_sql_table('tablekot', con=engine, columns='time')
    tiu = pd.read_sql_table('tablekot', con=engine, columns='tuhgaz')
    labels = tit
    values = tiu
    return render_template("newdiagram.html", labels=labels, values=values)
# labels=labels, values=values
File "C:\Flask_gd\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 325, in read_sql_table
table = pandas_sql.read_table(
File "C:\Flask_gd\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1479, in read_table
return table.read(
File "C:\Flask_gd\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1005, in read
cols = [self.table.c[n] for n in columns]
File "C:\Flask_gd\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
cols = [self.table.c[n] for n in columns]
File "C:\Flask_gd\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\base.py", line 1210, in __getitem__
return self._index[key]

KeyError: 't'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
    tit = pd.read_sql_table('tablekot', con=engine, columns='time')
    tiu = pd.read_sql_table('tablekot', con=engine, columns='tuhgaz')
```

The `columns` parameter is expected to be a sequence of table names.  A sequence is usually a list or a tuple.  A string also counts as a sequence, but it's a sequence of letters.  So, you were asking for columns called 't', 'i', 'm', and 'e'.

Use this:

```
    tit = pd.read_sql_table('tablekot', con=engine, columns=['time'])
    tiu = pd.read_sql_table('tablekot', con=engine, columns=['tuhgaz'])
```

Comment: I tried to change everything that I can,
corrected square brackets []. It's all the same that something from a trifle does not work, a small something. The list does not work. Something is missing from the little things.

Comment: Well, you certainly aren't getting the SAME error.  If you are, then you didn't make the change I suggested.  You should update your question with your new code and the new traceback.